# AlchemyAPI News API returning old news

Tags: alchemyapi

I've been doing some research on the News API in the AlchemyAPI. I found that sometimes it would return news that are years ago even I included "start=now-1d&end=now" in my query. Can anyone tell me how to fix this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

please see

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/251815/results-from-alchemy-newsapi-showing-old-content.html#answer-254410

I had the same issue.

HTH,
Brendan

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative API to crawl news from multi sources, you could consider Newsriver (https://newsriver.io).
It's a very recent API to retrieve structured online news articles.
Newsriver covers a large number of sources, and it's fully configurable, allowing you to set the age of the articles, the source, keywords, and much more.